# Сделать прокрутку в блоке в полной версии сайта как на тач-устройстве

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть такой код:

```css
.content{
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  column-count: 4;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque blanditiis doloribus nihil consequuntur culpa modi sed minus tempore dolorum dolore quasi possimus quo porro labore, nisi, sequi earum, excepturi numquam!
  Veniam earum odio accusantium! Sequi nam nobis ut assumenda? Aspernatur, veniam dolores reiciendis laboriosam architecto perspiciatis omnis similique atque, quasi, inventore voluptate fuga voluptas debitis maiores autem natus provident qui.
  Voluptates, aspernatur a! Natus totam aliquam perferendis sapiente consequuntur inventore ipsam fugit dolorum ea reiciendis, tenetur velit soluta exercitationem molestiae et enim eum quasi omnis sunt quisquam excepturi. Earum, eveniet!
  Exercitationem voluptatibus nemo mollitia non nobis veniam aut, consequatur praesentium. Aliquid sunt explicabo deleniti blanditiis. Iure ea voluptatem quaerat voluptas repellendus culpa quis dolores animi. Odio repudiandae aspernatur eos saepe!
  Facilis repellat porro cumque maiores earum illo at ducimus cupiditate? Maxime architecto ut repudiandae eius velit magni cumque sapiente, exercitationem mollitia molestiae minima? Officia perspiciatis nisi adipisci cum corrupti cumque.
  Rerum, aliquid sit. Maiores tenetur nostrum, eligendi dolor dicta consequuntur placeat eos quisquam optio aliquid quo facilis eius temporibus nulla natus hic architecto! Blanditiis vel fugiat corrupti! Quisquam, est quasi!
  Accusamus necessitatibus, quibusdam, architecto voluptas, beatae harum corrupti saepe fugit ad rem ipsam voluptate amet nulla consequatur consectetur omnis! Reiciendis neque architecto accusantium excepturi debitis est fugit ullam soluta modi!
  Soluta saepe quos tempore aliquam harum reprehenderit, amet numquam odit delectus cum nesciunt assumenda rerum, officia quibusdam non vitae fugiat laboriosam possimus in incidunt omnis. Amet autem quisquam nisi illum.
  Quam temporibus neque et, animi repudiandae deserunt ea consectetur. Ducimus iste consectetur dolorem iure eius pariatur possimus, obcaecati porro. Rerum pariatur tempora ea ratione ullam quibusdam quaerat magni vero obcaecati.
  Nemo, assumenda deleniti dolorem odio in quisquam accusantium voluptates fuga dicta velit totam cumque quis praesentium quidem id ipsum eum quas maxime laborum, ducimus quam. Molestias nobis maiores qui blanditiis.
</div>
```

Надо упростить прокрутку, чтобы не искать полосу прокрутки, по дизайну она вообще минимизируется.
Как сделать в этом блоке прокрутку как на тач-устройствах: кликаешь в любом месте этого блока, удерживаешь, тянешь, текст перетаскивается следом на мышью? Или может подключить перемотку по колесику мыши - вопрос как?

Comment: Попробуй библиотеку, https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 1**
Есть хорошая либа на чистом JS - https://github.com/asvd/dragscroll/blob/master/dragscroll.js
Подключили к проекту(или просто код на страницу добавьте) и добавили класс *.dragscroll* элементу, что должен прокручиваться левой кнопкой мыши.
CDN - https://cdn.rawgit.com/asvd/dragscroll/master/dragscroll.js

```js
/**
 * @fileoverview dragscroll - scroll area by dragging
 * @version 0.0.8
 * 
 * @license MIT, see http://github.com/asvd/dragscroll
 * @copyright 2015 asvd <heliosframework@gmail.com> 
 */


(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['exports'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
        factory(exports);
    } else {
        factory((root.dragscroll = {}));
    }
}(this, function (exports) {
    var _window = window;
    var _document = document;
    var mousemove = 'mousemove';
    var mouseup = 'mouseup';
    var mousedown = 'mousedown';
    var EventListener = 'EventListener';
    var addEventListener = 'add'+EventListener;
    var removeEventListener = 'remove'+EventListener;
    var newScrollX, newScrollY;

    var dragged = [];
    var reset = function(i, el) {
        for (i = 0; i < dragged.length;) {
            el = dragged[i++];
            el = el.container || el;
            el[removeEventListener](mousedown, el.md, 0);
            _window[removeEventListener](mouseup, el.mu, 0);
            _window[removeEventListener](mousemove, el.mm, 0);
        }

        // cloning into array since HTMLCollection is updated dynamically
        dragged = [].slice.call(_document.getElementsByClassName('dragscroll'));
        for (i = 0; i < dragged.length;) {
            (function(el, lastClientX, lastClientY, pushed, scroller, cont){
                (cont = el.container || el)[addEventListener](
                    mousedown,
                    cont.md = function(e) {
                        if (!el.hasAttribute('nochilddrag') ||
                            _document.elementFromPoint(
                                e.pageX, e.pageY
                            ) == cont
                        ) {
                            pushed = 1;
                            lastClientX = e.clientX;
                            lastClientY = e.clientY;

                            e.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }, 0
                );

                _window[addEventListener](
                    mouseup, cont.mu = function() {pushed = 0;}, 0
                );

                _window[addEventListener](
                    mousemove,
                    cont.mm = function(e) {
                        if (pushed) {
                            (scroller = el.scroller||el).scrollLeft -=
                                newScrollX = (- lastClientX + (lastClientX=e.clientX));
                            scroller.scrollTop -=
                                newScrollY = (- lastClientY + (lastClientY=e.clientY));
                            if (el == _document.body) {
                                (scroller = _document.documentElement).scrollLeft -= newScrollX;
                                scroller.scrollTop -= newScrollY;
                            }
                        }
                    }, 0
                );
             })(dragged[i++]);
        }
    }

      
    if (_document.readyState == 'complete') {
        reset();
    } else {
        _window[addEventListener]('load', reset, 0);
    }

    exports.reset = reset;
}));
```

```css
.content{
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  column-count: 4;  
}
```

```html
<div class="content dragscroll">
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque blanditiis doloribus nihil consequuntur culpa modi sed minus tempore dolorum dolore quasi possimus quo porro labore, nisi, sequi earum, excepturi numquam!
  Veniam earum odio accusantium! Sequi nam nobis ut assumenda? Aspernatur, veniam dolores reiciendis laboriosam architecto perspiciatis omnis similique atque, quasi, inventore voluptate fuga voluptas debitis maiores autem natus provident qui.
  Voluptates, aspernatur a! Natus totam aliquam perferendis sapiente consequuntur inventore ipsam fugit dolorum ea reiciendis, tenetur velit soluta exercitationem molestiae et enim eum quasi omnis sunt quisquam excepturi. Earum, eveniet!
  Exercitationem voluptatibus nemo mollitia non nobis veniam aut, consequatur praesentium. Aliquid sunt explicabo deleniti blanditiis. Iure ea voluptatem quaerat voluptas repellendus culpa quis dolores animi. Odio repudiandae aspernatur eos saepe!
  Facilis repellat porro cumque maiores earum illo at ducimus cupiditate? Maxime architecto ut repudiandae eius velit magni cumque sapiente, exercitationem mollitia molestiae minima? Officia perspiciatis nisi adipisci cum corrupti cumque.
  Rerum, aliquid sit. Maiores tenetur nostrum, eligendi dolor dicta consequuntur placeat eos quisquam optio aliquid quo facilis eius temporibus nulla natus hic architecto! Blanditiis vel fugiat corrupti! Quisquam, est quasi!
  Accusamus necessitatibus, quibusdam, architecto voluptas, beatae harum corrupti saepe fugit ad rem ipsam voluptate amet nulla consequatur consectetur omnis! Reiciendis neque architecto accusantium excepturi debitis est fugit ullam soluta modi!
  Soluta saepe quos tempore aliquam harum reprehenderit, amet numquam odit delectus cum nesciunt assumenda rerum, officia quibusdam non vitae fugiat laboriosam possimus in incidunt omnis. Amet autem quisquam nisi illum.
  Quam temporibus neque et, animi repudiandae deserunt ea consectetur. Ducimus iste consectetur dolorem iure eius pariatur possimus, obcaecati porro. Rerum pariatur tempora ea ratione ullam quibusdam quaerat magni vero obcaecati.
  Nemo, assumenda deleniti dolorem odio in quisquam accusantium voluptates fuga dicta velit totam cumque quis praesentium quidem id ipsum eum quas maxime laborum, ducimus quam. Molestias nobis maiores qui blanditiis.
</div>
```

**Вариант 2**
Это я про перемотку колесиком.

```js
let divScrollEnabled=document.querySelector('.content'),
    wheel="wheel"||"mousewheel"||"MozMousePixelScroll",
    scrollToMarg=e=>{  
      e.preventDefault();
      ((e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta)>0)?
        divScrollEnabled.scrollLeft+=100:
      divScrollEnabled.scrollLeft-=100;
    };
(divScrollEnabled.addEventListener)?
  divScrollEnabled.addEventListener(wheel, scrollToMarg):
divScrollEnabled.attachEvent(wheel, scrollToMarg);
window.onunload=()=>divScrollEnabled.removeEventListener('mousewheel',scrollToMarg);
```

```css
.content{
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  column-count: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fermentum felis nec justo ultricies rhoncus. Ut dictum nisl sit amet maximus euismod. Cras ut orci euismod, rutrum lacus quis, aliquet orci. Fusce felis risus, porttitor dapibus neque ut, bibendum accumsan nibh. Morbi sollicitudin mi nec erat pretium consectetur. Suspendisse sed eros lorem. Nulla pretium risus eget nisl pulvinar, sit amet fermentum quam laoreet. Cras neque augue, sagittis at sollicitudin aliquam, fermentum ut orci. Nunc sagittis orci a viverra dapibus. Maecenas accumsan porttitor orci.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fermentum felis nec justo ultricies rhoncus. Ut dictum nisl sit amet maximus euismod. Cras ut orci euismod, rutrum lacus quis, aliquet orci. Fusce felis risus, porttitor dapibus neque ut, bibendum accumsan nibh. Morbi sollicitudin mi nec erat pretium consectetur. Suspendisse sed eros lorem. Nulla pretium risus eget nisl pulvinar, sit amet fermentum quam laoreet. Cras neque augue, sagittis at sollicitudin aliquam, fermentum ut orci. Nunc sagittis orci a viverra dapibus. Maecenas accumsan porttitor orci.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fermentum felis nec justo ultricies rhoncus. Ut dictum nisl sit amet maximus euismod. Cras ut orci euismod, rutrum lacus quis, aliquet orci. Fusce felis risus, porttitor dapibus neque ut, bibendum accumsan nibh. Morbi sollicitudin mi nec erat pretium consectetur. Suspendisse sed eros lorem. Nulla pretium risus eget nisl pulvinar, sit amet fermentum quam laoreet. Cras neque augue, sagittis at sollicitudin aliquam, fermentum ut orci. Nunc sagittis orci a viverra dapibus. Maecenas accumsan porttitor orci.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fermentum felis nec justo ultricies rhoncus. Ut dictum nisl sit amet maximus euismod. Cras ut orci euismod, rutrum lacus quis, aliquet orci. Fusce felis risus, porttitor dapibus neque ut, bibendum accumsan nibh. Morbi sollicitudin mi nec erat pretium consectetur. Suspendisse sed eros lorem. Nulla pretium risus eget nisl pulvinar, sit amet fermentum quam laoreet. Cras neque augue, sagittis at sollicitudin aliquam, fermentum ut orci. Nunc sagittis orci a viverra dapibus. Maecenas accumsan porttitor orci. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fermentum felis nec justo ultricies rhoncus. Ut dictum nisl sit amet maximus euismod. Cras ut orci euismod, rutrum lacus quis, aliquet orci. Fusce felis risus, porttitor dapibus neque ut, bibendum accumsan nibh. Morbi sollicitudin mi nec erat pretium consectetur. Suspendisse sed eros lorem. Nulla pretium risus eget nisl pulvinar, sit amet fermentum quam laoreet. Cras neque augue, sagittis at sollicitudin aliquam, fermentum ut orci. Nunc sagittis orci a viverra dapibus. Maecenas accumsan porttitor orci.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fermentum felis nec justo ultricies rhoncus. Ut dictum nisl sit amet maximus euismod. Cras ut orci euismod, rutrum lacus quis, aliquet orci. Fusce felis risus, porttitor dapibus neque ut, bibendum accumsan nibh. Morbi sollicitudin mi nec erat pretium consectetur. Suspendisse sed eros lorem. Nulla pretium risus eget nisl pulvinar, sit amet fermentum quam laoreet. Cras neque augue, sagittis at sollicitudin aliquam, fermentum ut orci. Nunc sagittis orci a viverra dapibus. Maecenas accumsan porttitor orci.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fermentum felis nec justo ultricies rhoncus. Ut dictum nisl sit amet maximus euismod. Cras ut orci euismod, rutrum lacus quis, aliquet orci. Fusce felis risus, porttitor dapibus neque ut, bibendum accumsan nibh. Morbi sollicitudin mi nec erat pretium consectetur. Suspendisse sed eros lorem. Nulla pretium risus eget nisl pulvinar, sit amet fermentum quam laoreet. Cras neque augue, sagittis at sollicitudin aliquam, fermentum ut orci. Nunc sagittis orci a viverra dapibus. Maecenas accumsan porttitor orci.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fermentum felis nec justo ultricies rhoncus. Ut dictum nisl sit amet maximus euismod. Cras ut orci euismod, rutrum lacus quis, aliquet orci. Fusce felis risus, porttitor dapibus neque ut, bibendum accumsan nibh. Morbi sollicitudin mi nec erat pretium consectetur. Suspendisse sed eros lorem. Nulla pretium risus eget nisl pulvinar, sit amet fermentum quam laoreet. Cras neque augue, sagittis at sollicitudin aliquam, fermentum ut orci. Nunc sagittis orci a viverra dapibus. Maecenas accumsan porttitor orci. </div>
```